# /dev/ttyUSB0 missing in CentOS on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, centos-5, modem, 3g

I'm trying to configure 3G USB modem in my CentOS 5.7 instance that I have installed on VirtualBox (Win7 x64 is my main system).

First of all I'd like to configure a dialer in `/etc/wvdial.conf`

```
[Dialer aero2]
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Phone = *99#
Username =;
Password =;
Init1 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","darmowy","",0,0
Auto DNS = on
```

The thing is that I can't figure out what's the equivalent of ttyUSB0 under VirtualBox hosted linux. I don't have anything like /dev/ttyUSB0 but the modem itself is being detected (as I can view contents of the dongle, etc).

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Check output of dmesg to see what devices are created. Probably you will have to use usb_modeswitch program (http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/) to enable modem functionality on device.